# Hibernate, @OneToMany и выборка из базы данных

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-jpa

Имеются два класса, связанные между собой:

1) Restaurant

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant")
private Set<Meal> meals = Collections.emptySet();
```

2) Meal

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Restaurant restaurant;
```

Работа с репозиторием основа на на Spring JPA, т.е. выборка всех ресторанов осуществляется через обычный запрос findAll();

```
@Repository
public interface RestaurantRepository extends CrudRepository<Restaurant, Integer> {
    List<Restaurant> findAll();
}
```

Возможно ли как-то соблюсти задуманную LAZY-выборку связанных с рестораном Meals без указания прописанного запроса с @Query в репозитории? Простыми словами - не доставать блюда при использовании findAll()

Comment: fetch = FetchType.LAZY говорит о том, что при загрузке сущности данное поле инициализироваться не будет. Оно будет проинициализировано только после обращения к нему, т.е. вызова  метода `getMeals()`

Comment: и как же мне быть? вручную писать @Query?

Comment: В каком смысле? При использовании Lazy он и не будет их доставать по умолчанию.

Comment: когда я пишу List<Restaurants> findAll() - достает вместе с блюдами, т.е. он обращается к getMeals();

Comment: А почему вы думаете что он обращается к getMeals();?

Comment: При том, что у меня все связанное с рестораном достается как Lazy(там еще и список голосов есть) - у меня вытаскивается вообще ВСЕ, связанное с рестораном - и блюда, и голоса.

возможно ли это из-за связи таблиц через FK?

Comment: @MaksimRybalkin видимо обращаетесь к этому полю в методе `hashCode` или `equals`, т.е. там и инициализируется, не обращайтесь к этому полю в указанных методах